# Completely reset Firefox because of Wine uses too much CPU

Tags: firefox, wine

I need to do a complete reset of Firefox because every time I open Firefox, Wine pops up and is being used which uses more CPU. I tried resetting it by Troubleshooting and I deleted its file. I can not uninstall or reinstall Firefox and I can not do anything without the original Firefox with Linux. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should install Firefox through the software center. Running it through wine is slow and not needed. Open the Software Center > Search for Firefox > Select Firefox > Install Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Same as previous answer just the command line version if you prefer. 
Purge any versions of firefox you have:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

then reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: As this seems like a configuration  issue, it would be worth removing the config files for Firefox too IMO `rm ~/.mozilla/firefox`